# Volume of a tetrahedron by using Triple Integral

Tags: calculus

I want to calculate the volume of the tetrahedron  given by the points $(1,0,0),(-1,0,0), (0,1,2),(0,-1,2)$. I have to do this by using the principle of Cavalieri.

In general, I know how to do this. First one must find the cross sectional area and then integrate over it to find the volume. But I don't know how to apply this here.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What are your thoughts on it? Which $3$ points would you choose as base?

Comment: I would choose (-1,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,-1,2). Is it helpful to interpret this as a plane?

Comment: Draw a picture. It would help. Also, notice the midpoints of the edges formed by the first pair of points, and the last pair of points. You can see that you can simplify your calculations by calculating the volume in a single octant

Comment: I already draw picture but it doesnt help me :/

Comment: Yes writing the equations of all $4$ planes would help in setting the bounds.

Comment: What do I do then with the 4 equations for the planes? Calculate the points of intersection?

Comment: But I still don’t know how to proceed. Can anybody help?

Comment: I got for the 4 planes: 4x-2z=-4 -4x-2z=-4 -4y-2z=0 -4y+2z=0

Comment: I solved it and I got 4/3 as volume. Thanks for alle the hints ;)